# How can I show multiple pages using dynamic data from database?

Tags: java, xml, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I am reading data from cassandra database and displaying in jqGrid. But it is showing same records on all the pages

i am using code from http://javahunter.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/jqgrid-example/

---

this is my jsp file:
Please suggest why pagination is not working.
thx in advance.

```
<title>User Grid</title>



 <script>
  function fillGridOnEvent()          //function called through ready function
 {
    // $("#jQGrid").html("<table id=\"list\"></table><div id=\"page\"></div>");
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    url:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/JQGridServlet?q=1&action=fetchData',
    datatype: "xml",
    // cellEdit:true,
    //     width:'1000',
    height: '500',
    // altRows: true,
    //  width: 1000,
    colNames:['SrNo','Source IP','Destination IP','Bytes Sent',"Bytes Received"],
    colModel:[
         {name:'srNo',index:'srNo', width:90,sortable:true,align:'center'},
         {name:'stdName',index:'stdName',   
    width:130,sortable:false,align:'center',editable:true},
         {name:'stdStd',index:'stdStd', width:100,sortable:false,align:'center'},
         {name:'stdRollNo',index:'stdRollNo', width:180,sortable:false,align:'center'},
         {name:'view',index:'view', width:100,sortable:false,align:'center'}
             ],
    multiselect: false,
    autowidth:true,
    paging: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    // viewpages: true,
     rowNum:10,
   sortname:'srNo',
   //   sortorder:asce,
     rowList:[10,20,30,40,50],
     // recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {10}",
     pager: jQuery('#page'),
     loadComplete:function()
          {

          },
     loadonce:false,
     caption: "Student Details"
     }).navGrid('#page',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
  }

      jQuery().ready(function (){
                        alert("in ready");
                        fillGridOnEvent();
                                });
 </script>


 </head>
 <style>
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {white-space: normal}
</style>

<body onload="fillGridOnEvent();">
<table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table>
    <div id="page" align="center" >
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, the information you have provided is not sufficient to answer your question. Give some details.

Comment: post some code dear so that it will be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not dealing with the paging information that is being sent to your controller.

If you look at the POST your grid sends when you page you will see it is sending this information to your controller.  Your controller can accept this information and then pick the page of information to serve back to the jqGrid

Ex the parameters your controller will expect

```
(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string filters)
```

A rough example of the paging logic to take this information and produce a different page of data for the jqGrid to display.

```
var pagedQuery = filteredQuery.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip((page - 1) * rows).Take(rows);
```

This is by no means code you can copy paste into your app but will set you on the right path to find examples and such for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't do Java but searching for java examples and focusing on the above snippets should give you some comprehensive examples very quickly.

Comment: Post your servlet code. I can suggest the modification required